# Entity Framework QueryFilters

Tags: c#

I have QueryFilters on Column Deleted of Table.
Then I have Ordered column Unique.
If I delete a row with Ordered = 20, Max Ordered is the max without Deleted = false, then 19.
If for next Ordered I want Max Ordered + 1 I have 20 and there is a duplicate exception.
Best whay is:

1. Use IgnoreQueryFilters
2. Every Unique key in DataBase must be thogheter Deleted  ex. Unique (Ordered, Deleted)

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: You can read
Best whay is:

1. Use IgnoreQueryFilters
2. Every Unique key in DataBase must be thogheter Deleted  ex. Unique (Ordered, Deleted)

Comment: Yeah I can read, and as I didn't understand what your question was the first time, reading the exact same sentence doesn't really help. Would your problem be solved if you declared the column as identity with auto-increment? You tagged your question [c#] but it isn't really clear if your problem lies in the c# side or in your database side